# Can you use boost.python to wrap an entire c++ api; so you are able to run the c++ api as single function from python?

Tags: python, c++, boost

Trying to run a c++ api from python using boost.python.

I have made the api (contains two .cpp files) to download data from a 3rd party but have recently been told I need be able to run it from python, and was told boost.python is the way to do it.

I was hoping I would be able to wrap the entire api to be able to call a single function from python which would do everything I have coded in the c++ side.

Is this possible?
I'm new to c++ and boost so please be precise.

Thanks in advance, happy to answer any questions needed - Hopefully I have given a clear enough explanation

Comment: What you're asking is possible. But no, that function cannot be called `main`. You should change the question in your title because the question you ask has the answer 'no', but it isn't really the question you have.

Comment: Okay thanks mate - will change the question now

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how I can do this? I have been going around in circles the last two days

Comment: I could probably give you an answer with some research on my part, but I have to run to the bus. :-)

Comment: Ahhh not a problem - hopefully someone will answer soon

Thanks again!

Comment: Habe you read any boost python examples?  For example, I google "boost python examples" and I get this https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/tree/master/01-HelloWorld - which seems pretty simple.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - that looks like an answer.

Comment: @Omnifarious That depends.  Maybe the OP did google the problem, found examples like that, and something went wrong.  We can always hope.

Comment: An API (application programming **interface**) would not contain any .cpp (source) files. The source files could contain your *implementation* of the interface (i.e. your library), but the interface itself is typically defined in header files; the interface is the set of function declarations that external code is allowed to call. It sounds like you want your API to consist of a single function. So my question to you would be: did you define a single C++ function that will accomplish all you want to accomplish from a single Python function call?